# Is it possible to sign xml document with openssl

Tags: unix, openssl, digital-signature

Is it possible to create a digital signature for a given xml document using command line in openssl?

**Expectation**

I'm interested in getting a value from command line that looks like below extracted from `ds:SignatureValue`

**Signature Method**: SHA1 with two transformations applied

```
ULNmpuKwXwHwqUMybbwnupC/y9WZo8hi0qy9S2GuWxSB8WVEyA7RB6Qy.........hSq5BVw==
```

Digital Signature for Reference only.

```xml
<ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<ds:SignedInfo>
    <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
    <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
    <ds:Reference URI="#pfx238f2615-2267-6ee6-efa9-24dd82d85764">
        <ds:Transforms>
            <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
            <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
        </ds:Transforms>
        <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
        <ds:DigestValue>6okYcbSa3y18LSbOBJTMMWN7/Rs=</ds:DigestValue>
    </ds:Reference>
</ds:SignedInfo>
<ds:SignatureValue> <!-- how to compute this value -->
    ULNmpuKwXwHwqUMybbwnupC/y9WZo8hi0qy9S2GuWxSB8WVEyA7RB6Qy.........hSq5BVw==
</ds:SignatureValue>
<ds:KeyInfo>
    <ds:X509Data>
        <ds:X509Certificate>
            MIIDuDCCAqACCQDpZiKUmwKtZTANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADCBnTEL.......cBnjt9gNFVPaL7+/P+enkq9Vx0thQHUaI+ndr1gpZE=
        </ds:X509Certificate>
    </ds:X509Data>
</ds:KeyInfo>
</ds:Signature>
```

I've the keys (public/private) already generated.

**My Attempts**

```sh
openssl dgst -sha1 -sign ../keys/client.pem -out sign.sha1 response.xml

# readable base64

openssl enc -base64 -in sign.sha1 -out sign.sha1.base64
```

I'm referencing this tutorial https://opensource.com/article/19/6/cryptography-basics-openssl-part-2

Comment: No, openssl does not support XML signatures

Comment: Thanks. what are my options plz, any other command utility? I'm running nodejs and the npm libraries don't work

Comment: I don't know any command line tools to sign XML. The XML signature is complicated. It is recommended that you look for a suitable library for node.js

Comment: ok, can you tell me how an xml is signed? i mean is it hashed first and then encrypted, whats the procedure?

Comment: Check this https://www.w3.org/TR/xmldsig-core2/. You may also find the wikipedia summary https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Signature useful